# Probability $\mathbb{P}[X_N = 1 | X_0 = 1]$ for a Markov Chain over $\mathbb{X} = \{1,2,3\}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

**Exercise :**

> Let $\{ X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov Chain over the space $\mathbb{X} = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ with the following transition matrix :
>   $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ p & 2/3 -p & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Calculate the probability $\mathbb{P}[X_n=1|X_0=1]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for the cases of ***a)*** $p=0$, ***b)*** $p =1/6$, ***c)*** $p=2/3$. How would you calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} P^n$ without many operations ?

**Attempt :**

First of all, I start by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for $P$, which are :

$$\det(P-\lambda I) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ p & 2/3 -p& 1/3 \end{vmatrix} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \dots \Leftrightarrow \lambda = \begin{cases} 1 \\ \frac{1}{6}\big(\pm\sqrt{6p-1}-1\big)\end{cases}$$

The problem I have though, is that for example, the case $p=0$ yields complex eigenvalues, which I don't know how to handle in terms of probabilities to continue on. Also, in the case $p=1/6$ we have a Jordan case, which still leaves us with a hard case for $P^n$. Any tips on how to calculate the given probability ?

Comment: The eigenvectors of the complex eigenvalues will be conjugates (because the matrix is real), so you can just diagonalize the matrix as usual and everything will work out. And the Jordan form case is not hard; try to work out P^2 or P^3 by hand and you'll see the pattern.

Comment: @MikeHawk From a stochastic perspective it's crazy work because you need also a multiplication for $\pi_n$.

Comment: Asking for the exact value of $P(X_n=1\mid X_0=1)$ for every $n$, is a useless display of cruelty (either that, or you miscopied $P$). The limit of $P^n$ when $n\to\infty$, on the other hand, follows readily from the results in your notes.

Comment: @Did I'm fine with the limit, it's elementary. I haven't miscopied anything so I guess it's a form of cruelty of our professor.. I found out after calculating it (one of the cases also leads to Jordan Decomposition so it's even longer).

Comment: @Did The complex case by the way seems weird since the probability vector that we derive has complex expressions which don't cancel out... which are also huge (calculated via matlab)

Comment: Even when $P$ has complex eigenvalues, the imaginary part of the formula for $P(X_n=1\mid X_0=1)$ **must** be zero, naturally. If this imaginary part does not "cancel out", then there is a mistake in your computations.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess its something like this:

$x_{n}$ = $A^{n}$ * $x_{0}$

$x_{n}$ = ($P^{-1} L^{n} P$) * $x_{0}$

Where P is the matrix made of all the eigenvectors of A, L is the matrix with the corresponding eigenvalues, and $x_{0}$ is the unit vector [1, 0, 0].

Since you only care about the probability Pr($X_{n}$ = 1 | $X_{0}$ = 1), you only care about the element $A^{n}_{0,0}$. Since you have complex eigenvectors, your final result should be real positive number.